# Multi-dimensional table (excelsheet) as an php array. Or any other ideas?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, phpexcel

I have a excelsheet with a table representing the price calculation for a tourplanning system.

You can download the sheet here: 
**https://www.dropbox.com/s/ctam8iwym9pumjz/Example.xlsx?dl=0**

Now, I want to build a PHP function like:

**priceCalc($kilometers, $numberOfPersons, $doubleTour)**

Example values of parameters:

- **$kilometers = 130.0;** *(double)*
- **$numberOfPersons = 4;** *(integer)*
- **$doubleTour = true;** *(boolean)*

**Result** has to be with these values **= 218.00 €** *(see excelsheet)*

How would you implement it the easiest way (without 3rd-party classes or extensions - pure PHP)?

Comment: You've tagged this question with `phpexcel`: have you actually looked at [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)?

Comment: Yes, but this should be the last option. We want to keep the system slim and don't want so many 3rd-party classes.

Comment: That's your choice.... you asked the easiest way to implement it; I indicated the easiest way.... of course, you can write all the calculation logic yourself in plain PHP

Comment: Okay, then I'll change the question a little bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
function getEcoPrice($distance, $persons, $doubleTour) {
$distance = ceil($distance); //round up to next integer

$startPrice = 69;
$endprice = $startPrice;

$amountPlusPerson = array(0, 0, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10); //first index is just for setting index = number of persons. value to add, if extra person.
$amountNextDistance = array(0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10); //first index is just for setting index = number of distance steps. value to add, if next distance is reached.
$amountDoubleTour = array(-20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20); //value to add, if doubleTour is enabled.

$index = 0;   

switch (true) {
    case $distance <= 130:            
        $index = 0;
        break;
    case $distance <= 160:
        $index = 1;
        break;
    case $distance <= 170:
        $index = 2;            
        break;
    case $distance <= 180:
        $index = 3;            
        break;
    case $distance <= 190:
        $index = 4;
        break;
    case $distance <= 200:
        $index = 5;
        break;
    case $distance <= 210:
        $index = 6;
        break;
    case $distance <= 220:
        $index = 7;
        break;
    case $distance <= 230:
        $index = 8;
        break;
    case $distance > 230:
        return 99999;
        break;
}

for($i = 0; $i <= $index; $i++) {
    $endprice += $amountNextDistance[$i];
};

for ($i = 0; $i <= $persons; $i++) {
    $endprice += $amountPlusPerson[$i];
}

if ($doubleTour) {
    $endprice = $endprice * 2 + $amountDoubleTour[$index];
}

return $endprice;
}
```

**function call:**

```
echo getEcoPrice(200.1, 2, false);
```